# CRM Core Exception Could not find valid session key form error

Tags: wordpress, php

I know there are lots of threads on this with no clear solution. Posting again for any new input. Using cicivCRM 5.39.0. [image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

In this case disabling the Yoast SEO Plugin allowed everything to start running without errors.

Comment: It should be emphasized that there is no clear solution posted previously because this is a symptom of a class of problems rather than a specific problem. You've posted what worked for you, but others will experience this symptom using other CMSs.  What is helpful is to note that the issue is often trickling down from the CMS, but it might equally be caused by an extension, or some kind of resource limitation.

Answer (score 0):

Loading that page shows a couple of failures getting files from `/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/persist/contribute/dyn`  Try clearing your cache and check that directory exists.